# Expected ")" Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

[image]I am writing a code in python(Vs code) and I have this error:

```
Expected ")"  Pylance
```

the error occurs in: `def main()`
I tried to run my main and print it to my screen. I googled it and couldn't find any solutions. How can I fix that?

This is my code:

```
#The main driver of our code , this will handle user input and updating the graphics 
def main():  

   p.init ()
   screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
   clock = p.time.Clock ()
   screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
   gs= ChessEngine.GameState()
   print(gs.board)
   loadImages() #only do this once, before the whille loop
   running=True
   while running :
    for e in p.event.get():
     if e.type == p.QUIT:
      running =False
 
   drawGameState(screen,gs)
   clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
   p.display.flip() 

 '''
Responsible for all the graphics within a currnet game state.
 '''
 def drawGameState(screen,gs):
  drawBoard (screen) #draw squars on the board
 #add in piece highlighting or move suggestions
 
 drawPieces(screen,gs.board) #draw pieces on the top of those squares

'''
draw the squares on the board the top left square is always light

'''
def drawBoard(screen):
 colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
 for r in range (DIMENSION):
   for c in range (DIMENSION):
    color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
    p.draw.rect(screen , color , p.Rect(c*SQ_SIZE,r*SQ_SIZE,SQ_SIZE_SQ_SIZE))

'''
draw the pieces on the board using the current Game.State.board
'''
def drawPieces(screen,board):
    for r in range (DIMENSION):
        for c in range (DIMENSION):
            piece=board[r][c]
            if piece != "--": #not empty squares
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece],p.Rect(c*SQ_SIZE,r*SQ_SIZE))
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: What line is causing the error? As far as I can tell you aren't missing any `)` in `main`.

Comment: def main():  here

Comment: I don't get any errors. Is there code before main?

Comment: from pygame.constants import QUIT

from ChessEngine import GameState
import pygame as p
#from Chess import ChessEngine
#import ChessEngine 

WIDTH=HEIGHT=512
DIMENSION =8 #dimension of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE=HEIGHT//DIMENSION
MAX_FPS =15 #for animations later on 
IMAGES= {}



def loadImages():
 pieces = ['wp','wR','wN',"wB",'wK','wQ','bp','bR','bN','bB','bK','bQ']
 for piece in pieces:0
 IMAGES[piece]= p.transform.scale (p.image.load("image/" + piece + ".png") , (SQ_SIZE,SQ_SIZE)

Comment: the code above my this comment is my full code (this code is before the main that i was wrote in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p.transform.scale(p.image.load("image/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)
```

You miss a right parenthesis after `(SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)`

```
p.transform.scale(p.image.load("image/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Comment: it was in my code i didnt copy that correctly

Comment: i debug it and i get this eror again   5, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\nadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\nadav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\nadav\Desktop\Chess\ChessMain.py", line 23
    def main():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Could you edit your question to past your code? And attach a picture will be much better.

Comment: okay , i edited my question and attacth a picture of my problem

Comment: You really miss a right parenthesis after '(SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE)'. It should be '(SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))'. The 'scale(' need the right parenthesis.

Comment: The linting sometimes a little nerd, the problem is above the location it prompt.